# Common expression language for users

Tags: regular-expressions, decision-problem

for my current project I am working with decision tables that uses expression to determine conditions. Currently the decision tables support [FEEL](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/dmn11/feel/language-elements/) expressions. A simple example table using feel expressions is shown below:

```
| visitors |           season            | dish  |
|    <4    |  "spring", "winter", "fall" | Veal  |
|  [4..8]  |       not("summer")         | soup  |
|    >8    |  "spring", "winter", "fall" | beans |
|    -     |          "summer"           | steak |
```

I think the table is pretty straight forward. The number of visitors determines the type of meal in any other season than summer, while in the summer the number of visitors is irrelevant. 
In the example also shows the limits of complexity of the FEEL expression language. For example the not("summer") is the same as "spring", "winter", "fall".

in the future, more complex conditions have to be allowed. The use of dates for example, and it should be possible to determine if the date is in the future or not. You might expect an expression like:

```
Date(input) > Date.Today                    // date is in the future
Date(input).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday   // date cannot be a sunday
Round(input) > 10                           // the float rounded must be larger than 10
```

The problem we have is that the users that will use and fill these tables will be smart, but will not be able to understand code, So i cannot use straight out code as expressions.

My question is if there already is an expression language that helps user express convey functional requirements to inputs, much like the FEEL expression language, but more complex? Or can I expect to create my own expression language, by expending the current FEEL expression language.

**EDIT:**

I hope that i can clarify what I'm looking for in my request below. I also update the link to the language elements page.

- What I hope to find is a expression language that is helps translate between unspecified code logic and human readable text. Users should be able to understand the written expression written as they will be able to read and edit the table values directly. The programming language responsible for executing the functions is not important at this point.
- The complexity of the functions will be what is shown above. Feel only has limited expressions that does not support this. Other functions will be included: `check if date is in the future/past/present, check if date falls on a weekend, regex pattern matching on strings, AND & OR logic`

Thanks for all the feedback so far, I will definitely look at the links.

Comment: You'd probably do ok with your own language. There are however many languages for formalizing requirements. For example [Gherkin](https://cucumber.io)

Comment: I don't think this is ontopic here. Tool requests are offtopic, so is programming. I'm not sure if this would fit best on [SO], [softwareengineering.SE] or [softwarerecs.SE]. Community votes, please!

Comment: @Raphael [softwarerecs.se] doesn't want language recommendations. [so] doesn't want recommendations of any kind. I'm less sure about [softwareengineering.se], but generally this is the sort of questions that most SE sites don't want.

Comment: In addition to the issues others have mentioned, I don't think the question is well-defined.  The only requirement we have is "much like FEEL but more complex" -- but that's super-vague.  Complex, how?  More generally, how are we supposed to evaluate potential answers?  It's not clear.  If you can edit the question to address all the feedback, please do so.

Comment: I'd suggest you spend some quality time searching on [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).  There are a bunch of relevant questions there, e.g., https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1737/13806.